# Need advice on creating Models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I plan to create a site for famous animals on the web, the homepage#index will display all the animals, and on the homepage, there will be some filters, to filter through Dogs, Cats, Others.

Now, being new to Rails, I am having a hard time figuring out how to set up a model like this.

If I create an Animal model,

**rails g model Animal name:string description:string**

Where do I exactly define a 'Dog, or Cat' to this particular item?

Do I need to add a category_id ?

**rails g model Animal name:string description:string category_id:integer**

What If I wanted the user to add/delete/edit the categories as well?

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: By category, do you mean species?

Comment: Draw out your schema on paper as a super-basic entity diagram.  This will help you massively.

Comment: Yes Species would probably make sense.  I'll draw out a diagram as you requested

Comment: From what I understood Dog or Cat is supposed to be the name of animal, so you create `Animal.create({name: "Dog"})`. So why do you need category?

Comment: "Grumpy Cat" would be the name of Cat, so somewhere I need to set Cat as the category.

Comment: Should I create a model like  --   rails g model Animal name:string category_id:string    -  Then to retrieve a certain category_id, use  Animal.where("category_id" => "Cat")  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a Category model and an Animal Model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  has_many :animals
end

class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Category
end
```

In this way your animal could be a shark, which is also a fish.  Or could be a cod, which is also a fish.  If the user chose to view all fishes they would see sharks and cod, but if they chose to view cod they would not see sharks.  Investigate 'acts_as_tree' for more info on this.

Should allow quite a lot of options for filtering!  You would need a parent_id column in your categories migration, and a category_id column in your animals migration.